# How to join tables?

Tags: join-tables

I know many posts is on the site about this but I can't understand how it work.

This SQL works.

```
SELECT wp_category.id, wp_ogloszenia_kupione.kategoria, klient_id
  FROM wp_category
  JOIN wp_ogloszenia_kupione ON (wp_ogloszenia_kupione.kategoria = wp_category.id);
```

How this translate to Wordpress `$wpdb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you should remember when you're using SQL in WordPress. The most important, I guess, would be table prefix.

So your query should look something like this:

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT kategorie.id, ogloszenia.kategoria, klient_id ".
    "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}category kategorie ".
    "JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}ogloszenia_kupione ogloszenia ON (ogloszenia.id = kategorie.id)";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: but my tables got name "wp_ogloszenia_kupione" not "ogloszenia" ps: me from POLAND :)

Comment: That's why I use their names in FROM part and then set aliases (you can then use these aliases in rest of your query). See: `FROM {$wpdb->prefix}kategorie kategorie` (so `kategorie` is an alias of `{$wpdb->prefix}kategorie`).

Comment: Your script is not working. This is work: SELECT category.id, ogloszenia_kupione.kategoria, klient_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}category category JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}ogloszenia_kupione ogloszenia_kupione ON (ogloszenia_kupione.kategoria = category.id). But my page loaded very long, why?

Comment: Well, I assumed your previous SQL (published in question) is correct...

Comment: but why my page loaded sow LONG?

Comment: Hmm, how should I know? I have no idea what do you do in your code. You've asked only how to convert SQL query to wpdb call ;)  It depends how many records you have in your DB and if these 2 db tables are correctly structured. If my answer is correct, pls mark it as correct one, pls.

Comment: Sory, this my problem i have on page weather api and this is trouble btw. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your query is actually good, it should be as simple as this -

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT wp_kategorie.id, wp_ogloszenia_kupione.kategoria, klient_id
  FROM wp_kategorie
  JOIN wp_ogloszenia_kupione ON wp_ogloszenia_kupione.id = wp_kategorie.id";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

I'd recommend reading the [Codex for $wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), it's really quite informative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this solution won't work, because `$wpdb->query` "returns an integer corresponding to the number of rows affected/selected" and not real results, AFAIR.

Comment: yes this is empty.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. Replace `query` with `get_results` and you should have your results. I have updated the answer to reflect this.